# How to integrate JIRA with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, integration, jira

How can I can integrate JIRA with Selenium WebDriver? Actually I want to execute test cases and report pass/ fail status for each test cases in JIRA.

Comment: You can use REST API of Jira  :https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very general, so my answer will follow suit.

Jira isn't exactly a TCM (Test Case Manager) application, though it's certainly possible to track tests using Jira... The point being, you'd likely be looking at a fair amount of custom code work trying to get test launch/scheduling capabilities integrated.  You'd be far better off using something like Jenkins or Team City for your kick off.

To get results back into Jira, you'd need two things.  First up is a test framework.  TestNG is a great match for Selenium, as is JUnit, assuming you're using the Java language binding.  Regardless of language, however, you will need a test framework alongside Selenium.  I'm unsure of any library off the top of my head that integrates a test framework into Jira, so there may be some custom code involved to capture the result of an automated test and relay those results into Jira, which is the second needed item.  As @Helping Hands mentioned, their REST API is likely a good place to start.  There may be a listener out there for TestNG that may do this, but a cursory google search didn't return any readily valuable information.

If I may opine a bit, I wonder if Jira is really the best tool for the job here.  I realize you may have constraints that restrict your options here, but I think integrating into Jira may be bit of wheel re-invention.  Tools like qTest or TestRail are purpose built for QA activities, integrate with Jira on their own, and provide support for automation results reporting out of the box.  I'm not saying what you want to do is a bad idea, just that there may be other options that may not require as much overhead to producing value.

I hope this helps.  If you can provide some more detail about your goals, I'd be happy to add more specific input.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Reply Tim, Let me be more clear about my goals. Actually We have integrated Zephyr (plugin) with jira. And uploaded test cases into them. There are more than 1000 test cases. My Objective here is to use Selenium(Java) and Automate these test cases in such a way that when I execute individual steps from my test cases I should be able to mark results (Pass/Fail) corresponding to each test case. Can you please let me know if this can be done?? Thanks !

Comment: I'd definitely recommend TestNG then.  You'll need to either find or create a Listener to get the results into Jira.  You won't get results resolution to individual steps, however, but you'd get a pass/fail for the entire test.  I still doubt there is a way to launch execution from Jira (at least to my knowledge), so look into either using an executable jar, TeamCity or Jenkins for execution scheduling and kick off.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work with JIRA with Selenium Web Driver based project by integrating [jira client](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/blob/master/README.md) as part of my utility classes. [This has nothing to do with selenium web driver]

Below example tells how to log defect in JIRA if any automated test gets failed. [This is just a sample. You can try mentioned scenario in question by yourself with reference taken from sample code below]

```
JiraClient jira = new JiraClient("<JiraUrl>", "<creds>");

public void createNewJiraIssue(ITestResult result, String projectName, String defectType, String defectSummary,
        String defectDescription, String defectReporter, String defectAssignee) {
    try {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

            /* Create new issue */
            Issue newIssue = jira.createIssue(projectName, defectType).field(Field.SUMMARY, defectSummary)
                    .field(Field.DESCRIPTION, defectDescription).field(Field.REPORTER, defectReporter)
                    .field(Field.ASSIGNEE, defectAssignee).execute();
        }
    } catch (JiraException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        if (ex.getCause() != null)
            System.err.println(ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Replace JiraUrl and creds with valid Jira credentials.

For every failure, you can log defect in Jira. You may want to add some intelligence to it in future such as look for duplicate tickets before creating a new one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing, what should be the class name for this? can we update pass/fail status as well, please?

Comment: Class Name could be anything. With each test result, we can update JIRA ticket status (or create new one if not created already). The way to do this:
1. try / Catch Assert statements in your tests.
2. In Catch, call create new issue method and add if condition that it checks for issue summary before creating a new JIRA ticket (since duplicate summary not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

There is any way I can add screen shot which I took while creating Jira ticket in selenium.