# How to Integrate automated selenium script with JIRA

Tags: selenium, automation, jira

I am uploading selenium test scripts in JIRA and want to Execute these test cases from JIRA and need to update the test result. I have installed ZepHr's add-ons in JIRA. I am facing an issue in executing the selenium script in JIRA. How do I execute the selenium script after uploading the test script?

Comment: Hi, check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684899/how-to-integrate-jira-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate JIRA with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684899/how-to-integrate-jira-with-selenium-webdriver)